# List shows black colour

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview to which i attach data using an Array adapter.
But when i scroll, i find the edges to be dark.

Why is this happening and how to stop it.
Any help please!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is just a hint that there is more data present at the end of the list.

try using

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

This will help

Answer (score 2):

If u add TextViews or Different Views to listview apply listview background color to background color of those views .then u did not get the black screen when u scroll the listview

Answer (score 0):

How does the hierarchy of your activity look like? If your UI only contains a ListView then it's easier to just inherit from ListActivity